# Is there a simpler way to write this React function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I feel like I'm repeating myself a lot in this React function. I need to check if most fields in my state are empty, but there's a few I do not want to check. So I am not sure how to do that.

Here it is:

```js
onSearchClick = () => {
  const {insightName, insightDescription, createdBy, category, role, insightSource, assignTo, endDate, startDate} = this.state;
  if(
    insightName === "" &&
    insightDescription === "" &&
    createdBy === "" &&
    category === "" &&
    role === "" &&
    insightSource === "" &&
    assignTo === "" &&
    (endDate === "" || endDate === null) &&
    (startDate === "" || startDate === null) 
  )
  {
    window.scrollTo(500, 0);
    this.setState({
      isFormValid: false,
    })
  } else if (
    insightName === "" &&
    insightDescription === "" &&
    createdBy === "" &&
    category === "" &&
    role === "" &&
    insightSource === "" &&
    assignTo === "" &&
    (endDate === "" || endDate === null)
  ) {
    window.scrollTo(500, 0);
    this.setState({
      showEndDateMsg: true
    })
  } else if (
    insightName === "" &&
    insightDescription === "" &&
    createdBy === "" &&
    category === "" &&
    role === "" &&
    insightSource === "" &&
    assignTo === "" &&
    (startDate === "" || startDate === null)
  ) {
    window.scrollTo(500, 0);
    this.setState({
      showStartDateMsg: true
    })
  } else {

    this.setState({
      showTable: true
    })
}
}
```

I want to follow the DRY principles but am not sure what to do! Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: create a function that will return a boolean for the most repeated condition, assign it to a variable and use it for the other conditions.

Comment: You could use a JavaScript validation library.

Comment: So put everything that is in common in one variable and use that variable with the stuff that is not common..

Comment: As every one mentioned make a function for comparison and you may put all fields in an array to reduce comparison operators `===` and use some iterator e.g. map or filter to for comparison

Comment: You should validate your inputs when they change and keep track of their validty. Then check against that when onSearchClick is called

Comment: @EmileBergeron What is a validation library that you would recommend?

Comment: I don't have one in mind, but looking at the popular ones, either stand-alone or integrated within React, you should be able to make a thoughtful choice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a variable to contain everything you're continually checking:

```
const isMostlyEmpty = insightName === "" &&
                      insightDescription === "" &&
                      createdBy === "" &&
                      category === "" &&
                      role === "" &&
                      insightSource === "" &&
                      assignTo === "";
```

Then you can reuse that in each of your statements:

```
if(isMostlyEmpty &&
   (endDate === "" || endDate === null) &&
   (startDate === "" || startDate === null)) {
        window.scrollTo(500, 0);
        this.setState({
          isFormValid: false,
        });
} else if (isMostlyEmpty &&
           (endDate === '' || endDate === null)) {
    window.scrollTo(500, 0);
    this.setState({
      showEndDateMsg: true
    });
} else if (isMostlyEmpty &&
           (startDate === '' || endDate === null)) {
    window.scrollTo(500, 0);
    this.setState({
      showStartDateMsg: true
    });
} else {
    this.setState({
        showTable: true
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the concated value of your variables equal an empty string instead of checking them one by one

```
const emptyValues = insightName + insightDescription + createdBy + category + role + insightSource + assignTo === "";
```

And put the `scrollTo` in the `if` block when the values are empty

```
onSearchClick = () => {
  const {
    insightName,
    insightDescription,
    createdBy,
    category,
    role,
    insightSource,
    assignTo,
    endDate,
    startDate
  } = this.state;

  const emptyValues = insightName + insightDescription + createdBy + category + role + insightSource + assignTo === "";

  const noEndDate = endDate === "" || endDate === null;  

  const noStartDate = startDate === "" || startDate === null;

  if (emptyValues) {
    window.scrollTo(500, 0);
    if (noEndDate && noStartDate) {
      this.setState({
        isFormValid: false
      });
    } else if (noEndDate) {
      this.setState({
        showEndDateMsg: true
      });
    } else if (noStartDate) {
      this.setState({
        showStartDateMsg: true
      });
    }
  } else {
    this.setState({
      showTable: true
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
invalidForm = (reason) => {
  window.scrollTo(500, 0);

  switch(reason) {
    case 'noStartDate': 
      return this.setState({ showStartDateMsg: true });
    case 'noEndDate': 
      return this.setState({ showEndDateMsg: true });
    default:
      return this.setState({ isFormValid: false });
  }
}

onSearchClick = () => {
  const {
    insightName,
    insightDescription,
    createdBy,
    category,
    role,
    insightSource,
    assignTo,
    endDate,
    startDate
  } = this.state;

  const hasEmptyFields = [
    insightName,
    insightDescription,
    createdBy,
    category,
    role,
    insightSource,
    assignTo,
    endDate,
    startDate
  ].filter((field) => field === '');

  if(hasEmptyFields) {
    return this.invalidForm();
  }

  if(!startDate) {
    return this.invalidForm('noStartDate');
  }

  if(!endDate) {
    return this.invalidForm('noEndDate');
  }

  return this.setState({ showTable: true });
};
```